# Implement methods class in separted files in typescript

Tags: typescript, this, lazy-loading

I try to define a class in a file and implements its method in separated files in order to use lazy loading.

For instance, here is the main class.

```js
export default class Foo {

  private bar() {
    console.log("private bar");
  }

  public baz() {
    console.log("public baz");
  }
  
  public async qux(): Promise<void> {
    const { default: qux } = await import("./qux");
    return qux.call(this);
  }

}
```

and here is the content of "./qux.ts" :

```js
export default function qux() {
  this.bar()
  this.baz();
}
```

This first error I got in this file is the following :

> "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation"

I also tried to set `"noImplicitThis": false` in my tsconfig. This remove my previous error but I can access to bar method which is private and I don't want this.

---

I tried an other implementation by removing the function binding and use typed parameter instead :

```js
export default class Foo {

  private bar() {
    console.log("private bar");
  }

  public baz() {
    console.log("public baz");
  }
  
  public async qux(): Promise<void> {
    const { default: qux } = await import("./qux");
    return qux(this);
  }

}
```

and here is the content of "./qux.ts" :

```js
import Foo from "./Foo";

export default function qux(this: Foo) {
  this.bar()
  this.baz();
}
```

And now the error is :

> "Property 'bar' is private and only accessible within class 'Foo'"

I would like to benefit of classes modifiers (public - private - protected) and lazy loading. What pattern should I use ?